# How to compress a base 64 jpeg string in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to develop a program that takes an image from the user's webcam (using `react-webcam` library), and then compresses it to send to a backend API, however I cannot seem to compress the base 64 jpeg image obtained from the webcam.

I have tried using `browser-image-compression` to try and compress it, however it expects the image data to be a blob instead of a jpeg format. And I cannot find a way to convert the base 64 string to a blob. Please find below the code:

```
import Webcam from "react-webcam"
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react"
import imageCompression from "browser-image-compression"

const App = () => {
    const webRef = useRef(null)

    const capture = async () => {
        const img = webRef.current.getScreenshot()
        // I need to convert img to a blob!
        const options = { maxSizeMB: 0.5, maxWidthOrHeight: 720, useWebWorker: true };
        const compressedImage = await imageCompression(img, options);       // It will raise an error here as it expects img to be of type: Blob
        // Send compressed image to backend API

    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="webcam-container">
                <Webcam
                    ref={webRef}
                    mirrored={true}
                    screenshotQuality={0.5}
                    className="webcam"
                    audio={false}
                    screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
                    width={720}
                    height={720}
                />
                <div className="webcam-button-container">
                    <button onClick={capture}>Capture</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

It doesn't really matter whether the image is jpeg or webp, just as long as it is compressed since sending it uncompressed takes way too long.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Please **do not** use Base64 encoding for binaries in JavaScript, such as images, video, etc because using Base64 (and `data:` URIs) increases the content-length by 25% **and** is processed synchronously, so it blocks the browser's UI/render thread. The DOM and JavaScript all support _proper_ binary data flows (with methods like `toBlob`, and the `Blob` and `File` APIs), and you can pass those around to `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest`, and Axios.

Comment: @Dai so how would I go about doing this if I can't use base64 (thats the type return from `getScreenshot()`?)

Comment: How is `getScreenshot` implemented? `webRef.current` does not have a declared type in your posted code.